# Magento 2 : unveil is not function

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am getting below error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unveil is not a function stuck in this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquerypopper',
        'jqueryunveil',
        'jquerybootstrap',
        'yttheme',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($, Popper) {
        <?php if($enableLadyLoading){ ?>
        function _runLazyLoad() {
            $("img.lazyload").unveil(0, function () {
                $(this).load(function () {
                    this.classList.remove("lazyload");
                });
            });
        }

        /*_runLazyLoad();
        $(document).on("afterAjaxLazyLoad", function (event) {
            _runLazyLoad();
        });*/

        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: share code where you have included unvail.js file

Comment: Have you tried `'js/jquery.unveil'` instead of just `'jqueryunveil'`? You may also need to "shim" `unveil` using `requirejs.config()` with `"js/jquery.unveil": {deps: ["jquery"]}`.

Comment: i tried but no luck

Answer (score 1):

**I was facing the same issue on the SM theme. After debugging the code, I found that the function is not called sometimes, which is why it throws an error. However, after moving the external JS code to my phtml, it's now working correctly.**

I hope it will work for you.

```
<script>
    require(["jquery"], function ($) {;
        (function ($) {

            $.fn.unveil = function (threshold, callback) {

                var $w = $(window),
                    th = threshold || 0,
                    retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1,
                    attrib = retina ? "data-src-retina" : "data-src",
                    images = this,
                    loaded;

                this.one("unveil", function () {
                    var source = this.getAttribute(attrib);
                    source = source || this.getAttribute("data-src");
                    if (source) {
                        this.setAttribute("src", source);
                        if (typeof callback === "function") callback.call(this);
                    }
                });

                function unveil() {
                    var inview = images.filter(function () {
                        var $e = $(this);
                        if ($e.is(":hidden")) return;

                        var wt = $w.scrollTop(),
                            wb = wt + $w.height(),
                            et = $e.offset().top,
                            eb = et + $e.height();

                        return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
                    });

                    loaded = inview.trigger("unveil");
                    images = images.not(loaded);
                }

                $w.on("scroll.unveil resize.unveil lookup.unveil", unveil);

                unveil();

                return this;

            };

        })(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquerywow',
        'jquerybootstrap',
        'yttheme',
        'domReady!',
    ], function ($,WOW) {
        wow = new WOW();
        wow.init();
        
        <?php if($enableLadyLoading){ ?>
            function _runLazyLoad () {              
                 $("img.lazyload").unveil(0,function(){
                    $(this).on('load', function() {
                        this.classList.remove("lazyload");
                    });
                });
            }
            _runLazyLoad();
            $(document).on("afterAjaxLazyLoad", function( event) {
                _runLazyLoad();
            });
           
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```